# Changing to default style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After this code, the css of button is still changed. I want to be back to normal css, when the button is not active.

JavaScript

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  $("#btn1").css({color:'red'})
  $('#story').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="story" style="display:none;">
    My div
</div>

<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Click Here" />
```

Comment: Look at `toggleClass` - http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: define to us what you mean by `when the button is not active`. i.e. if you mean the default inactive state use Joffrey Maheo's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="story" style="display:none;">My div</div>
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Click Here" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#story').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Some CSS:

```
.active {
    color:#f00;
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7LaeB/

Answer (score 2):

Why not add class to that button?

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); // If has class, removes it, otherwise, it adds that class
    $('#story').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class with the changes you want and apply it when active and remove it when inactive. For example:

JS:

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('#story').fadeToggle(400)
});

//then when the button is 'inactive' run removeClass('active')
```

CSS:

```
.active{color:red;}
```